# Connecting two entities in Firebase in Firebaserecycleadapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Cardview which is working already. Here is the code:

```
  @Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model, ViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter =
        new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model, ViewHolder>(Model.class,R.layout.row,ViewHolder.class,mref)
        {

            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, Model model, int position) {
                String userid = model.getUserid().toString();


                viewHolder.setDetails(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),model.getPetname(),"Reason:" + model.getReason(),model.getPetpicture(),"Breed:" + model.getBreed(),
                       "Age:  " + model.getAge(),"Size: " +  model.getPetsize() +"yrs old","Color:" + model.getPetcolor(),model.getUserid(),model.datepost);
            }
        };

    recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
}
```

That model.getUserid() get the user Id of the user who posted that it display UID given by Firebase. Now what I want is to convert that UID to name which I have from other Entity User:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXyqM.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfMtK.png)

So in short I want to populate my Cardview but instead of Userid I want to convert it to name.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is that after retrieving that userId, you fetch the name using a value event listener as follows
                                                                             DatabaseReference userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User");

```
    String userId = "the_user_id";

    userRef.child(userId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists())
            {
                String name = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class).getName();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });`
```

Comment: Thank you for answering where will i put the value listener inside the firebaserecycle adpater or before it? sorry newbie here

Comment: Thank you for answering done trying it only shows one account name

Comment: You put the listener after getting the user id , that is, after your call to `String userid = model.getUserid().toString();`